# How can i capture a global touch event?

Tags: events, xamarin.forms, uwp, touch

i have a Xamarin application in UWP that has multiple screens which build up while being used. on each screen there are multiple controls in which they can enter information. what i am trying to do is - if the screen has not had any interaction in the way of a touch / click from the user then to time out and go back to the beginning. i can of course capture the event of each control that has been touched and reset but i was wondering if there is like a 'Global' touch event that will fire when the screen is touched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if there is like a 'Global' touch event that will fire when the screen is touched.

Sure, For UWP you could add `PointerEntered` event handler for current [`CoreWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.corewindow) and it is *Global* on the top level. Please refer the following steps.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerEntered += CoreWindow_PointerEntered;
}

private void CoreWindow_PointerEntered(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.PointerEventArgs args)
{
    // do some stuff
}
```

Comment: Don't mention it! 